# x elements right to one element

Tags: html, css

A thing that drives me crazy at the moment. I want to align four smaller elements right to one big element.

```
+-----------------+-------------------------+   +     + 
|                 |          title          |   |     | 30px
|                 |-------------------------+   | 1   +
|                 |                         |   | 2   |
|      thumb      |          text           |   | 0   | 60px
|                 |                         |   | p   |
|                 |-------------------------+   | x   +
|                 | views |  flag  (space)  |   |     | 30px
+-----------------+-------------------------+   +     +
```

I tried `float:left` and `float:right` as well as `clear:right` in all imaginable combinations, with `span` as well as `div{display:inline}`. It just doesn't want to behave as I'd expect it to behave.

I know this can be achieved with `display:table`, but I'm curios why the combination of `float:left` and `clear:right` doesn't work as in my case.

This is my code (sorry for the mixed up *style.css*, but this is just what it looks now after hours of exhausting work):

**row.php**

```
<div class="wide media-library">
    <div class="inner">
        <!-- (...) -->
        <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
            <div class="row" data-id="<?php echo $row['video_id']; ?>" data-resource-id="<?php echo $row['video_resource_id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $row['video_id']; ?>">
                <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(/<?php echo $row['slideshare_thumb_url']; ?>)"></div>
                <div class="title"><?php echo $row['name_en']; ?></div>
                <div class="text"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></div>
                <div class="views"><?php echo $row['no_of_views']; ?></div>
                <div class="flag" style="background-image: url(/<?php echo $row['flag_image_path']; ?>)"></div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- (...) -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**style.css** (*broken*)

```
.wide.media-library {
    color: #000;
}

.wide.media-library .inner {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.wide.media-library .header {
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.wide.media-library .header h2 {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

.wide.media-library .header p {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.wide.media-library .filter {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.wide.media-library .filter input {
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 27px;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 11px;
    width: 290px;
}

.wide.media-library .filter select {
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 22px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 240px;
}

.wide.media-library .row div {
    display: inline;
}

.wide.media-library .row .thumb {
    background-size: 120px 68px;
    float: left;
    height: 120px;
    width: 68px;
}

.wide.media-library .row .title {
    float: right;
}

.wide.media-library .row .text {
    float: right;
}

.wide.media-library .row .views {
    float: right;
}

.wide.media-library .row .flag {
    background-size: 16px 12px;
    float: right;
    height: 12px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8n0pLkx/)

Comment: Why not a 'parent' wrapper around the elements that will be on the right that can then be floated or otherwise made to be on the right side?

Comment: Where are your HTML elements with `class` "media" and "medium"? They are in your CSS but not in your HTML.

Comment: @putvande Just a mistake I did when altering the styles for the question to make it more comprehensible. Changed it to the actual state, as it also was in the JSFiddle already.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fbgz8bmt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, just remove the floats on the right elements:

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c94zfn6c/

**OR Code Snippet:**

```css
.wide.media-library {
 color: #000;
}
.wide.media-library .inner {
 display: block;
 font-size: 14px;
 height: auto;
 position: relative;
}
.wide.media-library .row div {
 display: block;
}
.wide.media-library .row .thumb {
 background: #CCC;
 float: left;
 height: 120px;
 width: 68px;
}
.wide.media-library .row .title {
    height: 30px;
}
.wide.media-library .row .text {
    height: 70px;
}
.wide.media-library .row .views {
    height: 20px;
    display:inline;
}
.wide.media-library .row .views:after {
    content:" |";
}
.wide.media-library .row .flag {
 background: #CCC;
 height: 20px;
 width: 16px;
    display:inline;
}

.row > div {
  margin-right:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wide media-library">
 <div class="inner">
  <!-- (...) -->
  <div class="row" data-id="1" data-resource-id="2" id="1">
   <div class="thumb"><!-- (thumb) --></div>
   <div class="title">Just a title...</div>
   <div class="text">... with just a description.</div>
   <div class="views">1337 views</div>
   <div class="flag">(flag)</div>
  </div>
  <!-- (...) -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just wanted to say *Thank you* real quick for your answer! For now, I'm really tired and on the hunt for some food, but I'll definitely look over it on the weekend.